# Simplify TcpListener application in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I have a simple application that can receive and send tcp data.
right now there's a thread used to start the listener and within this thread there's another thread to receive.

it works but it seems like a waste of resources. Can the connect be simplified?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    private readonly TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1980);
    private NetworkStream sendStream;
    private NetworkStream recvStream;
    private TcpClient client;
    private byte[] datalength = new byte[4];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ServerReceive()
    {
        recvStream = client.GetStream();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (recvStream.Read(datalength, 0, 4) != 0)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
                recvStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Client : " + Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                });
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public void ServerSend(string msg)
    {
        sendStream = client.GetStream();
        var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
        var length = data.Length;
        datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
        sendStream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
        sendStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    private void btnListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            ServerSend(txtSend.Text);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        server.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Waiting For Connection");
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected To Client");
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                ServerReceive();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not knowledgable enough in this but you can use the async methods (BeginAccept, BeginRead et al)

Answer (score 1):

Various things about your code seem odd.

**Field level values**

There's no reason for these variables to be declared at a class level, you only ever use them within a single function:

```
private NetworkStream sendStream;
private NetworkStream recvStream;
```

**btnSend_Click bug**

If the user clicks on the send button, before they've clicked on the Listen button, your `client` member won't have been initialised so will throw an exception when you do:

```
if (client.Connected)
```

**Listen/Read Thread**

It looks like you're only expecting a single client (your listen thread doesn't contain a loop to accept more than a single connection).  Rather than spinning up another thread to perform the receive functionality, you might as well be doing it in the same thread that you performed the listen on.

**Listen Management**

Your listen code doesn't check the state of the Server before calling start.  If you click it twice, it seems likely that this is going to cause a problem.

**Exception Handling**

You don't have any exception handling around your read/write calls.  TCP can be a bit of a pain at times, depending upon how the connection has been shutdown it may throw various exceptions rather than just returning 0 from the read call.  It's also worth remembering that since you're accessing the socket from multiple threads it can change state between your is `connected` call and your `write` operation.